# Django select_related in reverse

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    some_campaign_field = models.CharField()

class Position(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
    some_position_field = models.CharField()

class Trade(models.Model):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    some_trade_field = models.CharField()
```

In other words, I have Campaigns which can have multiple Positions. In turn each position within the campaign can have multiple Trades.

Is there an efficient way (ie: minimal database calls) to select a Campaign along with all of its associated Positions and Trades. It doesn't look like I can use `select_related` because that only works the other way, eg: for a specific Trade, `select_related` will get all of the associated Positions.

Currently I am doing this in nested loops as follows:

```
campaigns = Campaign.objects.get()
for campaign in campaigns:
    positions = campaign.position_set.all()
    for position in positions:
        trades = position.trade_set.all()
        # do stuff
```

This works correctly but is very inefficient in terms of how many times the database gets hit. I there a better way to do this? Something along the lines of `select_related` but in reverse? A way to do one large query to get all Campaigns along with the associated Positions and Trades without having to loop through each individually.

Comment: What about `prefetch_related`? It does a separate lookup and updates the instance for many-one and many-many relationships in python.

Comment: prefetch_related and also get only needed fields by .values() and .values_list()

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I was aware of prefetch_related but didn't really understand what it was for. Until now.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to the suggestions in the comments, I ended up with the following working solution:

```
open_campaigns = list(Campaign.objects.prefetch_related(
                                       Prefetch('position_set',
                                                queryset=Position.objects.all(),
                                                to_attr='cached_positions'),
                                       Prefetch('cached_positions__trade_set',
                                                to_attr='cached_trades'),
                                       ).filter(exit_datetime__isnull=True))
```

**Edit**: this import is also required

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
```

Ref. [Prefetch docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)

Comment: how did you manage to access cached_positions?

Comment: This might be the only question and answer on the topic out there! Nice solution and thanks. I've been looking for something like this for a while. I've got a similar set of relations I've been struggling with WRT serialization.