# How can I prefetch nested data in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```py
class Contract:
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        to="Product",
        through="ContractProductThroughModel",
        related_name="contracts"
    )

class Product:
   garage = models.ForeignKey(
        to="Garage",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Garage:
    ...
```

Is there a way to prefetch all contracts for all garages?
I tried it like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652520/django-select-related-in-reverse):

```py
garages = Garage.objects.all().prefetch_related("product_set").prefetch_related(Prefetch("product_set__contracts", to_attr="cached_contracts"))
```

but I want to access the cached contracts for each garage object like this `garage.cached_contracts`.

Is that possible?